# Kartik mpdf stops without generating PDF

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I am working on a project which is in Yii2. There is a feature that allows users to export their data in PDF. I am using kartik-v/yii2-mpdf.

```
"kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "dev-master",
```

**The PDF contains styling, tables, text, and images.**

The logic is written such that it will create 100 pages and then merge them to create 1 PDF.

The issue is that it stops working without giving any warning/error/exception. A 0-size PDF is generated in the last which might cause this issue but I am not sure why it happens.

[image]

Before generating the PDF I overridden the memory limits and max execution time.

```
        ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        set_time_limit(0);
```

But it didn't help.

All this is done through a CRON job.

Comment: You do not provide enough information. Show your code. Use [logging](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html) and share logs.

Comment: @Finwe, kartik-mpdf does not provide any way to enable logs, but I tried to modify the core files in the vendor folder, and locally I can see the logs but on production, it is not working might be because we have YII_DEBUG set to false.